# update_post_meta() not working when used with WordPress action

Tags: post-meta, post-status

I am trying to update the field when post status changes to published. It is getting the values properly but not updating when I check the what update field is returning.

It shows some number.

Please help not sure whether I should use this along with `transition_post_status`

---

**Update - I have tried below hooks** // the action is getting triggered but the fields are not updating

*1. **publish** //works but no update is happening*

*2. **save_post** && **save_post_l** //works but no update is happening.*

---

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 3);
function updated_to_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

    if ($new_status == 'publish')) // I have removed the check for post type 
  {

        $post_id = $post->ID;

        if (get_field('advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)) {

            if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {

                $metatitle = get_field('seo_title', $post_id);
                $metadesc = get_field('seo_meta_description', $post_id);
                $metakeywords = get_field('seo_keyword', $post_id);


                update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $metatitle );
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $metadesc );
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', $metakeywords);

            }

        }

    } else {
        return;
    }

}
```

---

---

### Update

I was able to solve the issue by using '`wp_insert_post`' action . Can I know why other actions failed but '`wp_insert_post`' worked?

code that i used for testing

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 3);
    function updated_to_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post)
    {

        if (($new_status == 'publish') && ($post->post_type == 'l')) {

            $post_id = $post->ID;

            error_log( var_export( $post_id, 1 ) );

            if (get_field('advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)) {


                if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {

                    // ACF field
                    $metatitle    = get_field('seo_title', $post_id);

                     error_log( var_export( $metatitle, 1 ) );

                    $metadesc     = get_field('seo_meta_description', $post_id);

                     error_log( var_export( $metadesc, 1 ) );
                    $metakeywords = get_field('seo_keyword', $post_id);

                     error_log( var_export( $metakeywords, 1 ) );
                    //plugin is activated


                    //old values 

                     $metadesc_old = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
                        error_log( var_export( $metadesc_old, 1 ) );
                     $metatitle_old = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
                         error_log( var_export( $metatitle_old, 1 ) );
                     $metakeywords_old = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', true);
                        error_log( var_export( $metakeywords_old, 1 ) );

                    update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', $metatitle, $metatitle_old);
                       error_log( var_export( $tyone, 1 ) );
                   update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', $metadesc, $metadesc_old);
                       error_log( var_export( $tytwo, 1 ) );
                     update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', $metakeywords, $metakeywords_old);  
                       error_log( var_export( $tythree, 1 ) ); 

                }

            }

        } else {
            return;
        }

        //Do something
    }
```

Comment: you say *when i check the what update field is returning it shows some number*, that is the ID of the metadata it just inserted, this means it has worked. From the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/): **Return: Meta ID if the key didn't exist, true on successful update, false on failure.**

Comment: @Milo But when i check it after updating the meta fields they are empty.  Yes but all the update field returns a number(ID). Not sure if i am using correct action.

Comment: @Milo the issue was with action . every thing works if i use wp_insert_post

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla, In the shared code you have used "($post->post_type == 'l')" this. Does your post_type or slug is  'l' this?

Comment: @ArpitaHunka Yes it's post type. I was able to make it work by using wp_insert_post , not sure why other actions didn't worked

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla, which plugin you are using for the SEO? Please share plugin link...
Because I have registered new post type 'l' and checked with default values, it's updating the field in DB.

Comment: I have used this code :
add_action('transition_post_status', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 3);
function updated_to_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
 if (($new_status == 'publish') && ($post->post_type == 'l')) {
       $post_id = $post->ID;
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', '_yoast_wpseo_title' );
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' );
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw');
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
So might be error in condition of getting data.

Comment: @ArpitaHunka  i am using acf to make the field and yoast plugin as seo, and i am mapping acf field to yoast please note that wp_insert_post is working working for me

Comment: If (you're 100% sure) the fields are not being updated, and you did get to the `update_post_meta()` part, then some possible causes are: a) the fields are already updated (i.e. new values equal the current values in the database, so `update_post_meta()` will update nothing); or b) a plugin/code is changing back (or removing) the field values. With the `wp_insert_post` action, the fields may have yet existed in the post being created/updated; hence that's likely why the `update_post_meta()` calls work.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yeah. may be some thing wrong with yoast. i have to try with the actual fields ..i think ..i will update after checking

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla, try using a test field - `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'test20181114', 'Test 20181114' );` - and see if the field is being added to the post. If it is, then your code works. PS: In my previous comment, I meant to say "When you tested with the `wp_insert_post` action".

Comment: @SallyCJ tired it , update is not happening but when i use ` wp_insert_post ` it works .. i think transition_post_status can't be used with update_post_meta

Comment: Yes it can, @LatheeshVMVilla. But the problem is probably because one of the three `if` expressions doesn't evaluate to a `true`. Try *temporarily* change the `get_field('advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)` to `true` and see if that works. If yes, then that means the post doesn't have the `advanced_option_edit_seo` field or that its value is empty.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes i have checked it. i enabled `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` and checked each variable with `error_log( var_export( $var, 1 ) );` they returns the correct  value every thing happens correctly just before update field...if it can be done then problem is with yoast plugin i think...so an off topic i guess :(

Comment: Post the full code you used that has the `error_log()` parts.

Comment: @SallyCJ i have updated the question,  i have tested `update_post_meta` with fourth parameter also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85748/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-latheesh-v-m-villa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I installed the [Yoast SEO plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), and tested your code, and now I can positively say "***neither no nor yes, but you could***" to this question:

> Please help not sure whether I should use this along with
>   `transition_post_status`

`transition_post_status` is fired *before* the `wp_insert_post` action is fired, and the Yoast SEO plugin is actually saving (adding/updating) all its custom fields via the `wp_insert_post` action:

```
// See WPSEO_Metabox::save_postdata() (in wordpress-seo/admin/metabox/class-metabox.php)
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', array( $this, 'save_postdata' ) );
```

So your code itself works, and the fields do get updated (if the new and current values are not the same and that all the `if` conditions are met, of course); however the Yoast SEO plugin overrides the value via the `WPSEO_Metabox::save_postdata()` function, which should answer this question:

> I was able to solve the issue by using '`wp_insert_post`' action . Can
>   I know why other actions failed but '`wp_insert_post`' worked?

**Why did I say *neither no nor yes, but you could*?**

Because you can use `transition_post_status` along with `wp_insert_post` like so:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'do_updated_to_publish', 10, 2 );
function do_updated_to_publish( $new_status, $old_status ) {
    if ( $new_status !== $old_status && 'publish' === $new_status ) {
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 2 );
    }
}

function updated_to_publish( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Remove it; it will be re-added via the do_updated_to_publish() function,
    // if necessary or when applicable.
    remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 2 );

    if ( ! defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' ) || 'l' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( get_field( 'advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id ) ) {
        // Make your update_post_meta() calls here.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', 'test' );
        error_log( 'focuskw updated for post #' . $post_id );
    }
}
```

Tried and tested working with Yoast SEO version 9.1.

Comment: PS: The `See WPSEO_Metabox::save_postdata()` should be `See WPSEO_Metabox::__construct()`. Sorry about that. And in the `updated_to_publish()`, you'd also want to check if `$post->post_status` is `publish`, because double-checking is always a good practice. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try "wpseo_title" Filter for updating wpseo_title.

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');

function filter_product_wpseo_title($title) {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
        if (get_field('advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)) {

            if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {

                $title = get_field('seo_title', $post_id);

            }

        }


    return $title;
}
```

for more seo data update example: https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/

Comment: Hello, thanks. Tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your original function relies on the $_POST['post_type'] being set to the appropriate value. As a general rule, you should avoid using global variables - if you use only want the function gives to you, you don't have to think about the contexts in what it should be called.

In this case, that's what's happened. You're function relies on a global variable $_POST['post_type'], and while that works in one 'state' (publishing a post) it doesn't in another (a cron job, updating a post). In short, $_POST['post_type'] isn't always what you think it should be.

The following retrieves the post type from the passed $post variable:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'updated_to_publish', 10, 3);
```

function updated_to_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

```
if (($new_status == 'publish') && (get_post_type( $post ) == 'l')) {

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if (get_field('advanced_option_edit_seo', $post_id)) {

        if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {

           //Code goes here

        }
    }

} else {
    return;
}
```

}

[Visit this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143364/if-problems-with-transition-post-status) from where I just have copied the answer

Comment: Hello , thanks ..Okay i have removed the check for post type..but now i am still having the problem...`transition_post_status` does not work, only `wp_insert_post` works.  May be answer to question is why `wp_insert_post` only works when updating the meta